# Объявление ListView в приложении, которое использует фрагменты

Tags: android, listview, java, массивы

Доброго дня! Прошу прощения за очень глупый вопрос, но не могли бы вы помочь мне вывести ListView в одном из фрагментов приложения? я без понятия как это сделать...вообще((

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
  <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvmain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

а что в самом классе писать???
попробовал так..

```
public class lol3 extends Fragment {

String[] colors = { "Красны", "Оранжевый", "Желтый", "Зелёный", "Голубой", "Синий", "Фиолетовый"};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.search);

    // Связываемся с ListView
    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvmain);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                                       (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,                                   colors);

    list.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private void setContentView(int search) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

private ListView findViewById(Object list) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

  }
```

но подсвечивает 
     ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                                           (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,    colors);

```
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
  }
```

Comment: поделитесь опытом, приведите пример, пожалуйста..

Answer (score 1):

во-первых, 
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, colors);
  подсвечивается, так как вы пытаетесть вместо Context впихать fragment, нужно либо getApplicationContext(), либо getActivity()

во-вторыйх, врагменту нужно указать какое View он будет отображать, поэтому свой метод **onCreate** замените на вот этот код

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{       
    final View content = inflater.inflate(R.layout.you_layout_with_listView,null);
    ListView list = (ListView) content.findViewById(R.id.lvmain);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,colors);

    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    return content;
}
```